# How to create a digital product download link that can't be used twice?

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, paypal

The goal is after people paid (PayPal or Stripe), they land on a download page.

You upload the file to /uploads for example. You can deny access to the dir with .htaccess.

I suppose if I then create a link `/uploads/product`, that a client can download it.

But that link can now be shared all over the internet.

What would be the best way to go about it?

I want to code it myself in PHP & JS if required.

Answer (score 1):

Rough idea:

- create a temporary download file. Use a random file name.
- create a program that will download the file. The program should delete the temporary download after a click on the download file link by the client
- send the download page (not the download file) link to the user, with a parameter that is the download file.

You could put some 'downloaded ok?' location on the download page, then delete the temp file afterwards.

Comment: Would it make things easier if the client had a WordPress user account?

Comment: Don't think that would make a difference. Assuming that the person completed the 'order' process, then the above psuedocode would work just fine. Only the person would get the link (after order payment/whatever), and it's a unique link - once someone used the link to get the file, the unique file (related to the link) is deleted. Anyone else with the link wouldn't get the file - you deleted it.